# How to startActivityForResult with a medium activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities A, B, C. I need to call A -> B -> C -> A. Activity A needs result from C but compulsorily calls B.

I did try below, but it does not work!:

> A calls startActivityForResult(B),  B calls startActivityForResult(C)
>   then B.finish(),  C has returnIntent to A then finish().

Thank you very much for any suggestion!!!

Comment: Can you explain more ? i thinks its unclear..

Comment: You can start `B` for result and from `B` start `C` for result. When `C` finishes it must give you either (Your wanted result or not), Then in `B's` `onActivityResult` (check whether C given you your wanted result or not If yes finish `B` as soon as you receive positive result) and send result back to `A`. That's simple.

Comment: @NitinMisra: sorry for late reply but your suggestion works!!

Comment: @HoaVu i posted it as answer so that other users can take advantage of it. If it helped do accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start `B` for result and from `B` start `C` for result. When `C` finishes it must give you either (Your wanted result or not), Then in `B's` onActivityResult (check whether `C` given you your wanted result or not If yes finish `B` as soon as you receive positive result) and send result back to `A`. That's simple. –

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing by this way you can send data using intents. & when you are on activity C, so whiling moving to activity A, you can just clear activity stack top, it will solve your problem same time your data will be passed from activity C to activity A.

Like below :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
 intent.putExtra("data", "data");
 startActivity(intent);
 finish();
```